# Do all Android devices have "option" and "back" buttons?

Tags: android, button

Do all Android devices have "option" and "back" buttons? Or should my design have "back" and "option" buttons for making it more versatile?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The [Android 4.1 CDD](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/source.android.com/en//compatibility/4.1/android-4.1-cdd.pdf) section 7.2.3 contains information on this:

> The Home, Menu and Back functions are essential to the Android
>   navigation paradigm. Device implementations MUST make these functions
>   available to the user at all times when running applications. These
>   functions MAY be implemented via dedicated physical buttons (such as
>   mechanical or capacitive touch buttons), or MAY be implemented using
>   dedicated software keys, gestures, touch panel, etc. Android 4.1
>   supports both implementations.

Answer (score 2):

The back button is going to bring back the previous screen on the stack regardless, much like the home button will pretty much always take you to the home screen. As for the option button, it's generally good practice to implement something for it if there are some settings to be changed or something like that, but that really depends on your application. Many apps don't utilize it and do just fine.

Answer (score -2):

No, not every device comes with a back button. Amazon Fire phone do not have a back key.

On Android platform it is always better to be cautious as device manufacturer always do customization.

Comment: Amazon Fire doesn't work with ANDROID, it's called Fire OS, it's a fork but not the same http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_OS. So this device cannot be catalogue as an Android device.

Comment: Not seeing that link says if it is different. yess they do not have Google services which is understandable, and those services are not part of Android.  Downloading some source code and tweaking some color and theme doesn't make that a new OS. We release same apk for Google play store and Amazon app store just disabling play services which works just fine. So far they just rebranded it with amazon services, nothing new. https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/platforms/android-fireos

Comment: Yes, it's said,  >It is forked from Android<. When you FORK something at the start could seems similar, but a fork could derive on irreconcilable code. So it's BASED on Android but IT'S NOT.

Comment: Even more, if you read this from android http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29#Licesing, you will see Android it's a trademark from Google, so if Google don't certificate your code, your are not getting Android as so. Whatever your code it's equals as Android code.

Comment: This answer appeared to me when I googled the question. I was about to take it without entering here. I'm sorry but I wish either Google doesn't show this answer or this answer be removed.